# How to make a true/false ternary operator simpler in a HTML template?

Tags: html, ternary, template-literals

Below a partial `html` template of mine; I find it quite ugly...
Is there a way to make `${dod.city === true ? true : false}` ternary simpler?
I couldn't find any way online.
Thanks a lot.

```
  <span data-desktop=${dod.city === true ? true : false} data-mobile=${dom.city === true ? true : false}>CITY</span>
  <span data-desktop=${dod.zipcode === true ? true : false} data-mobile=${dom.zipcode === true ? true : false}>ZIPCODE</span>
  <span data-desktop=${dod.building === true ? true : false} data-mobile=${dom.building === true ? true : false}>BUILDING</span>
```

Comment: What about `${!(!0!==dod.city)}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only wanted to pass true or false in `data-desktop` and `data-mobile` then you can do something like this:-

```html
<span data-desktop=${!!dod.city} data-mobile=${!!dom.city>CITY</span>
  <span data-desktop=${!!dod.zipcode} data-mobile=${!!dom.zipcode}>ZIPCODE</span>
  <span data-desktop=${!!dod.building} data-mobile=${!!dom.building}>BUILDING</span>
```

Comment: I didn't know about `!!`. Thanks I learn something.